# How to remove whitespaces between words Liquid-C (Shopify)

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm using Shopify API to request the phone number of the user by using {{customer.phone}} as a *checkout script*, but the request gives me a number with whitespaces between numbers like this:
123 456 789

How can I remove whitespaces from this output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To modify a String you need to use a Shopify String filter. You can check out more details in the documentation: https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/filters/string-filters

Below is a code which will return the phone numbers without spaces:

```
{{ customer.phone | remove:" "}}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want for example to convert:

- 1,000.00 USD to 1000.00 you can use this code:

```html
{{ product.price_min| money_without_currency | remove:","}}
```

- 1,000.00 USD to 1000 you can use this code:

```html
{{ product.price_min | money_without_currency | remove:"," | remove:"." | divided_by: 100}}
```